# Evaluating $\int_{x=0}^{1} \frac{\cos^2x}{\sqrt{x}}$ with Taylor series

Tags: integration, limits, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals

I'm asked to use a Taylor series to expand and simplify the integrand, and then look at the leading term behavior near $\infty$ to determine if the integral converges or diverges.

I used the Taylor series for $\cos x$:

$$ \cos x = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

$$ \cos^2 x = (\cos x)^2 = \left(\frac{x^0}{0!} - \frac{x^2}{2} + H.O.T.\right)^2 = 1 -x^2+\frac{x^4}{24} $$

$$ \frac{\cos^2x}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \mathcal O\left(x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right) $$

Looking at the leading order term, $ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $, it appears to converge:

$$ \lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \infty$$

I've gone through the calculations a few times and feel confident about the answer I've outlined, but I'm still getting this one marked wrong. Any mistakes stand out?

Comment: This is really the same as the last one, and again you are right. Who is telling you otherwise? I don't understand why you are taking that limit, though.

Comment: It's an online course. I've gone through the same calculation more than a few times but must be entering the answer incorrectly or something.

Comment: @qbert, my understanding is that looking at the limit is what is meant by "analyze the behavior of the leading order term".

Comment: But you care what it's doing at $0$, not at $\infty$. Also, the integrand going to infinity tells you little about the integral beyond "be careful." You care about how fast it's going

Comment: Note that $\int_0^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt x }}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0 + } \int_\varepsilon ^1 {\frac{{dx}}{{\sqrt x }}}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{\varepsilon  \to 0 + } (2 - 2\sqrt \varepsilon  ) = 2$.